# How to update multiple divs when using several AJAX requests with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am building a page using jQuery, fetching data via ajax from a website.

I have an array of data which I loop over, creating a number of divs with unique ids. I then create an ajax request, with the success function being used to fill in the content of these divs.

The issue that I am having is that when the success function is run, it doesn't know which div to update.

Code looks something like this (written from memory).

```
<div id="page"></div>
...
var counter = 1;
["intro","about","links"].each( function (index) {
   var frag='<div id="id_'+counter+'"></div>\n";
   $("#page").append(frag);
   $.ajax({
      url: "/data/"+index,
      success: function (response) {
         $("#id_"+counter).html(response.responseText);
      }
   });
   counter++;
}
```

I think the issue that I'm having is that counter reaches 3 by the time the ajax function returns, so #id_+counter is #id_3 for all requests, rather than id_1, id_2 and id_3.

What is the correct way in which this request should be written?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating over a simple list of strings. You can store the section along with it's target element as an object then iterate.

```
<div id="introDiv"></div>
<div id="aboutDiv"></div>
<div id="linksDiv"></div>

var sections = [
    { section: "intro", target: "introDiv" },
    { section: "about", target: "aboutDiv" },
    { section: "links", target: "linksDiv" }
];

$.each(sections, function(index, value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data/" + index,
        method: "get"
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        $("#" + value.target).html(result);
    });
});
```

You can dynamically create the element too but I made them static to illustrate the mapping. You'll also need a delegate to find the dynamically created element.

If you want the numeric id... you don't even need to know the target since it's all being created on-the-fly.

```
var sections = ["intro", "about", "links"];
$.each(sections, function(index, value) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/data/" + index,
        method: "get"
    })
    .then(function(result) {
        var div = $("<div></div>").attr({ id: "id_" + index });
        div.html(result);
        $("#page").append(div);
    });
});
```

But you can't guarantee the order of the responses -- that's the nature of the asynchronous requests.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `counter` variable, you can use `index` which should work as you want it to since you aren't incrementing it, rather it is managed by the loop.

I've not tested it, so I'm not sure if it works as expected.

```
["intro","about","links"].each( function (index) { 
    var frag='<div id="id_'+(index+1)+'"></div>\n"; 
    $("#page").append(frag); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/data/"+index, 
        success: function (response) { 
            $("#id_"+(index+1)).html(response.responseText); 
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have the server send the index back as part of the ajax response. Then you could just do something like this:

```
<div id="page"></div>
...
var counter = 1;
["intro","about","links"].each( function (index) {
   var frag='<div id="id_'+counter+'"></div>\n";
   $("#page").append(frag);
   $.ajax({
      url: "/data/"+index,
      data: {index: index},
      success: function (response) {
         $("#id_"+response.index).html(response.responseText);
      }
   });
   counter++;
}
```

Alternatively, instead of sending `data: {index: index}`, you could just make the server parse the index out of the URL text.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the Ajax to run synchronously, so the each loop will wait for your Ajax to finish before incrementing `counter`.

```
var counter = 1;
["intro","about","links"].each( function (index) { 
    var frag='<div id="id_'+counter+'"></div>\n"; 
    $("#page").append(frag); 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/data/"+index, 
        success: function (response) { 
            $("#id_"+counter).html(response.responseText); 
        },
        async: false
    }); 
    counter++; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this could be very slow if there are lots of page (this was just an example). Are there any other approaches I could look at, other than sync mode?

Comment: You can see my other answer which leaves it as asynchronous. I'm leaving this one since it could be helpful to others and it technically works

Comment: The AJAX documentation explicitly recommends against synchronous requests, and for good (explained) reasons.  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp